# Capturing random number of repetitions

Tags: php, pcre

I wish to capture a random number of isbn numbers from an html string. One such string could be

```
978-2-7560<br />978-2-84055<br />978-2-84789<br />978-2-906187<br />
```

Ideally I would use one regex that would capture each repetition separately with preg_match_all. Of course I can capture the whole string like so:

```
(([\d-]{7,}<br />)+)
```

Then split it by

```
"<br />",
```

but I'd rather use only the one regex. Is that possible?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can't be done. As an example, what I wanted to do was to capture array(a, a, a, a, a) from the string "aaaaa", using a simple regex, with a random number of 'a's.
I will close it, sorry for the effort guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use a second capture group and some non-capture magic:

```
(?:([\d-]{7,})<br />)+
   ^--inner  ^--inner
^--outer            ^--outer
```

The `?:` makes the outer group non-capturing, so you'll be left with captures of only the isbn portions.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the non capturing tip. Another thing I didn't know. However it doesn't do what I want, which is to capture multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `explode()`.

```
explode("<br />", $string);
```

Note that this might break assuming the format of the `<br />` tag changes (`<br>`, `<br/>`).